# Steps to integrate PrimeNG with JHipster

Tags: webpack, jhipster, primeng

We have been trying to incorporate PrimeNG components into a JHipster (angular 4) generated project with no success. After download and install PrimeNG into our project, we are able to import classes but when we include the corresponding tags into templates nothing is drawn. We have tested several of the PrimeNG components. Also we have done the imports in app.module, etc. I would like to be more concrete, but no error is displayed anywhere. Do you have any hint on how work with PrimeNG and JHipster together?
Thanks

Comment: Have you imported CSS?

Comment: Yes I have included them. Do you know how can I check that css files are correctly imported?

Comment: Easy just search for one of primeng classes (e.g. ui-widget) in generated bundle. Which theme have you included? Myself, I've used Bootstrap theme to have something visually integrated with JHipster generated pages.

Comment: Did you follow the PrimeNG installation guide? It's hard to tell your issue as you don't give any information... If you use Yarn and follow the PrimeNG guide, it should work out-of-the-box in a few minutes (I did it last week !)

Comment: Gaël, Julien, thank you so much for your help. I have followed the PrimeNG installation guide but probably, as Gaël said, there is something wrong with styles, probably I am not importing them correctly, as I am not sure about the correct way of doing it with webpack. I am gathering all relevant information for coming back with a concrete case. 
By the way, reading over here and other JHipster pages, I have seen you both are involved in the creation of the framework: congratulations, it is an amazing project!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following steps worked for us.

**1-** Add dependecies with `yarn`

```
yarn add primeng
yarn add @angular/animations
```

**2-** Created new component with ng cli, standing on the same folder where you want to create the component run

```
ng g component new-cmp
```

This will

- Create a `new-cmp` folder with the `.html` and `.ts` that you need.
- Import and declare the component in the closest module, for example `home.module.ts`

**3-** Add the `imports` of the prime components you want to use along with the `BrowserAnimationsModule` on the module where the new component was declared, in our case `home.module.ts` for example:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AccordionModule, RatingModule, CalendarModule, ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

**AND** add them to the imports array inside the @NgModule

**4-** Go to `src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss` and import the styles, like Marcin Krajewski suggests:

```
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css';
```

**5**- Add a prime component for testing in the html of the created component, for example `<button pButton type="button" label="Click"></button>`

**6-** Run `yarn run webpack:build` so the apps picks up the changes from `vendors.scss`

**7-** Run `yarn start` and test it out!

**UPDATE**
Jhipster version: 4.5.2

Comment: The command in step 6 is changed to `yarn webpack:build` instead of `yarn webpack:build:vendor`

Answer (score 5):

I just got PrimeNG working with JHipster 4.4.1 (using Angular4 and SCSS).

Julien's comment above, and Marcin's answer about `vendor.css`, combine to give you the solution. However, as a newcomer to JHipster, even after reading this thread, it took me a couple tries to put that together correctly.

So, to clarify, here is what worked for me:

---

**1. Install PrimeNG and dependencies**

Run `yarn add primeng` to install PrimeNG as a dependency for your app.

Run `yarn add @angular/animations` (see [PrimeNG Setup Guide](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) for an explanation of this).

---

**2. Add the PrimeNG styles to your app**

Instead of using `.angular-cli.json` to add the styles to the build, simply `@import` them in your `vendor.scss` (or `vendor.css`). For me, that meant adding these two lines at the end of `content/scss/vendor.scss`:

```
@import 'node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min';
@import 'node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme';
```

Run `yarn run webpack:build:vendor`.

If, like me, your build fails because it cannot find a few image files, I got around it by simply copying the `node_modules/primeng/resources/images/` directory into `content/scss/`. Perhaps someone has a more "correct" way to solve this, but that workaround did the trick for me.

---

**3. Make sure animations are included in your module**

If they weren't already, make sure you're importing animations in any module that will use PrimeNG (I did this on my root module):

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

Don't forget to also add this to the @NgModule `imports` array.

---

**4. Start using PrimeNG!**

Now everything should be wired up -- just follow PrimeNG's docs to import and use their components within yours.

i.e. `import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/primeng'` (also add to @NgModule `imports`).

Comment: I have accepted the other answer because in my case I have vendor.css and the imports are the correct one. Anyway, thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: That's why I clarified I used SCSS in mine, but yeah no worries. We answered at the same time anyway, if I had seen cjmm's I wouldn't have typed mine because they are basically the same.

Comment: Can you please suggest the best solution for that images error?

Comment: If you're referring to the build failing because it cannot find PrimeNG's image files, all I did was exactly as it says in step 2 above: copy the `node_modules/primeng/resources/images/` directory into `content/scss/`, so that the JHipster webpack config finds it where it looks for it. I haven't used JHipster or Angular in several months, so the paths might be different now, but for me they were in the error message.

Answer (score 4):

This is a solution that worked for me with other module (`angular-calendar`) and it imports styles from `node_modues` directory

Add to file:

**vendor.css :**

```
@import "~angular-calendar/dist/css/angular-calendar.css";
```

and run

```
yarn run webpack:build:vendor
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update for PrimeNG 6**

Follow top answers here but also need to add primeicons dependency. [See my answer here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977105/how-to-use-jhipster-5-with-primeng-6/52018091#52018091)

- Run cmd `yarn add primeicons`
- In `vendor.css` add `@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';` (not sure if import order matters)