# How to Integrate PrimeNG editor in angular app created with Jhipster

Tags: angular, editor, jhipster, primeng

I am trying to integrate `PrimeNG editor` in `JHispter` generated `angular` app.
I have followed the PrimeNG site for the  [general instructions](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) and  [editor instructions](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor):

1. `npm install primeng --save`
2. `npm install @angular/animations --save`
3. `npm install quill --save`
4. Add Quill to scripts in `angular-cli.json`
5. Imported `EditorModule` in `home.modules`
6. Added `<p-editor [(ngModel)]="text" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"></p-editor>` in the html file
7. executed `npm start` command to run the app.

The UI looks like below 
[image]
and getting below error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: Quill is not defined
>       at Editor.ngAfterViewInit (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/primeng/components/editor/editor.js:36)
>   [image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you followed these instructions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162427/steps-to-integrate-primeng-with-jhipster

Comment: @GaëlMarziou tried above instructions also. This error is, because the home module is not able to find `quill.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

Added the following line into my webpack.common.js to the plugins and now it is working.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Quill: "quill" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I am not sure this is the proper solution but it worked for me -

add below line to the index.html -

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.5/quill.min.js" integrity="sha256-OEsiRE77EL46ZjgPqmsXfsNcOQPrMG/M6hHBF65jXP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```