# How to use JHipster 5+ with PrimeNG 6+

Tags: angular, webpack, jhipster, primeng

I tried:

- [official getting started guide for PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)
- [Steps to integrate PrimeNG with JHipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162427/steps-to-integrate-primeng-with-jhipster) (sorry if this is a duplicate post, have no rep to comment there)
- [generator-jhipster-primeng](https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng)

and some other articles and stackoverflow posts with no luck on getting the latest PrimeNG 6+ to work with the latest JHipster 5+. It *mostly* works, but the styles are a bit off - mainly it seems like primeicons aren't working.

For example, I tried the [primeng filter table example](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter) and it mostly works except the icons such as the dropdown arrows appear as empty boxes as well as others not appearing correctly. I suspect this may have to do with primeicons not importing correctly?

Has anyone got this to work? I tested using a fresh install of everything but I can post code if really needed.

Comment: Did you import the css files (under `Styles Configuration` in the official guide) in your vendor.css?

Comment: Yep, otherwise styles would be completely wrong. Is it working for you?

Comment: Hmm it seems to almost be working now, styles are only a tiny bit off for me still. I'll keep testing with it some more and see, otherwise I'll post a sample repo. Definitely `generator-jhipster-primeng` doesn't seem to work out of the box and the official PrimeNG examples require changing fa-icons to angular style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys it's working for me, I just got tripped up on using `generator-jhipster-primeng` which doesn't work out of the box. Steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162427/steps-to-integrate-primeng-with-jhipster) mostly work, just have to include primeicons. I included full directions below anyways.

However, the **layout/css styles are still somewhat off** (maybe they conflict with JHipster/bootstrap) and you'll have to tweak some of the official PrimeNG examples, such as using `<fa-icon>` instead of old `<i>` style icons.

Steps to integrate PrimeNG into JHipster project:

### 1. Add dependencies

- `yarn add primeicons primeng @angular/animations`
- may need to use the same version of Angular core for animations to avoid problems

### 2. Import css styles

In `vendor.css` (or `vendor.scss` if you use Sass) add:

```
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
@import '~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css'; // pick whatever theme
@import '~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css'
```

- Notice the bootstrap theme layout is especially off. Other themes are found in `node_modules/primeng/resources/themes`

### 3. Import modules

- I added `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `app.module.ts` but you may be able to just add it where needed:

  - `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`
  - Add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `@NgModule` imports array as well
- Import whatever PrimeNG module as needed (follow documentation from their examples)

---

And that's it! Now follow PrimeNG docs for using specific components.

**Tested with `jhipster 5.2.1`, `primeng 6.1.2`, and `primeicons 1.0.0-beta.10`**